# How to read in a text file and store content in seperate arrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files

My classes are the following: Room, Drawers, Shorts, Tops, and Socks. I have arrayLists roomList, drawerList, shortList, topList, and sockList in their designated classes. I also have a text file(room.txt) in which I need to read in the contents and store them in the appropriate arrayList.
The text file looks something like this:

Room 1, White,BlackStripes,3
Drawer 1,Black,Large,3,2,4
Drawer 2,White, Small,4,1,2
Short 1,Blue, M, 32
Short 2,Yellow, L, 34
Short 3, Orange, S, 28
Top 1,Green,L, 10
Sock 1, White, L, 20
Sock 2, Red, L, 18

Basically I'm having trouble putting the content in the right place. This is what my code looks like:

```
try{
Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("room.txt"));
while(read.hasNextLine())
{ 
  Room myRoom = new Room();
  Drawers myDrawers = new Drawer();
  Shorts myShorts = new Short();
  Tops myTops = new Tops();
  Socks mySock = new Socks();

  // What goes here, including comma delimeters, and counters etc


  myRoom.setName(//What goes here);
  myRoom.setColor();
  myRoom.setStripes();
  myRoom.SetDrawerAmount();
  Room.roomList.add(myRoom);

  myDrawers.setName();
  myDrawers.setColor();
  myDrawers.setSize();
  myDrawers.setContainers();
  myDrawers.setKnobs();
  myDrawers.setItem();
  Drawers.drawerList.add(myDrawers);

  myShorts.setname();
  myShorts.setColor();
  myShorts.setSize();
  myShorts.setNumSize();
  Shorts.shortList.add(myShorts);

  myTops.setName();
  myTops.setColor();
  myTops.setSize();
  myTops.setNumSize();
  Tops.topList.add(myTops);

  mySocks.setName();
  mySocks.setColor();
  mySocks.setSize();
  mySocks.setPairs();
  Socks.sockList.add(mySocks);
    }
}

catch (Exception e)
{
System.out.println("Error File Not Found");
}
```

Basically, I'm not sure how to format at it to know when I should add to roomList, or drawerList, or shortsList, or topsList, or socksList, since there are different numbers of lines and different numbers of content per line.

Comment: This sounds like you are asking us to fill the empty gaps in your homework. Did you at least try to work on those gaps? Did you search on "java text parsing" for starters?

Comment: I did try many things, but now that you mention java text parsing I will look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You must write a custom parser for that kind of files.
Your parser must read each line, then split the line by commas "," (see String.split() method). That gives you an String[] for each line.
Once you have the String[], compare the first element with "Rooms", "Drawers", etc... in a *switch* statement or *if/else*.

You must process each element of the String[] in order to classify your objects. Do this in a separate method. Your method should returns a Room, Drawer, Shorts, etc. to the caller, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You don't tell us what the classes Room, Drawer... look like so there is your problem :)

Why don't you use plain old lists?

```
List<Room> rlist= new ArrayList<Room>();
List<Drawer> dlist= new ArrayList<Drawer>();
```

so on and so forth, then it is this easy:

```
rlist.add(myRoom);
```

then on and on again

Answer (score 0):

@eyp has good advice. In addition,

- Scanner can be frustrating at times. If it works for you, go with it. Otherwise, read up on other java I/O classes like FileReader and BufferedReader. You can compose a BufferedReader and a FileReader (See the example in the BufferedReader documentation: [Java Standard Edition Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/).) It's almost as easy as using Scanner, it gives you the readLine() method you need, and it allows you to do more advanced I/O in the future.
- If the different classes were subclasses of a common superclass, you could put a lot of the parsing into the superclass constructor to avoid repeating it for each subclass. Look at what each line in your text file is made up of, and I think you'll be able to recognize a common superclass. Then each subclass could handle the part that is specific to it.